# Can you use Win32 GUI in a browser plugin?

Tags: c++, winapi, npapi, browser-plugin

Of course it would mean you're plugin is not cross-platform but let's focus on the technical side...

Is a browser plugin (like done in NPAPI) restricted in what it can do? Or do you get fairly free reign to access the PC and the render-window you're given? For instance can you create Win32/MFC controls in your browser this way?

*A side question - is your browser plugin* conceptually *akin to a .DLL, which is therefore just arbitrary compiled code implementing a specific interface for browser control/communication?*

Comment: Why would you want to stab your eyes out and insult the work of all the abstraction the browsers give you?

Comment: Welcome to the real world. Maybe I already have a code-base involving such code, and it's more important to get it online in _some fashion_ quickly for business users who all use Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 types of NPAPI plugins: windowed and windowless plugins. Both of them has some advantages and disadvantages (see [this link](http://neugierig.org/software/chromium/notes/2009/07/windowed-windowless-plugins.html)). When you deal with windowed plugin on Win32 you get HWND of browser plugin window and you can work with it like with any window in OS.

Comment: Nice link. Bit over my head on first read but full of insight.

Comment: Windowless plugins (not fully supported by FireBreath yet but hopefully will be before FireBreath 1.4 hits RC -- we'll see if we get it in time) basically give you the HDC instead of a HWND and tell you when to draw. Either way you can use win32 gui.